# Android Arcgis 100.3: How to get center Point of MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, arcgis

How to get Point from ArcGis's MapView center of the screen, which representing its latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float centreX=mapView.getX() + mapView.getWidth()  / 2;
float centreY=mapView.getY() + mapView.getHeight() / 2;

android.graphics.Point screenPoint = new android.graphics.Point(Math.round(centreX), Math.round(centreY));
Point mapPoint = mv.screenToLocation(screenPoint);
Point wgs84Point = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(mapPoint, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());

double lat = wgs84Point.getY();
double lng = wgs84Point.getX();
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, it is very easy to get center coordinates put the line below

```
 LatLng target = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

get the latitude and longitude by accessing the latitude and longitude member of latlng class

```
target.latitude;
target.longitude;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but LatLng is part of Google Maps library which I'm not currently using (I'm using ArcGis 100.3), so...